# Powershell: Convert each file in folder to UTF-8 csv

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I need a script to convert excel to csv format UTF-8. I think it can be done on Powershell, but I can’t. Can you see where the error is? Thank you very much in advance.

```bsh
$configFiles = Get-ChildItem  "c:\HR\test"

foreach ($file in $configFiles) {
    $a = -join ("c:\HR\test", "\", $file)
    Get-Content $a | Set-Content -path -Encoding utf8 $a
}
```

Comment: are the files excel files OR are they csv files? powershell DOES NOT directly handle excel files ... [*grin*]

Comment: on input it excel on output it csv. This code is work but i need to apply this code to all files in folder   `Get-Content .\template1.csv | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 test-utf8.csv`

Comment: @Lee_Dailey while you're correct about Powershell's lack of "native" Excel handling, the functionality is only an Import-Module away: https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel. ;)

Comment: @derekbaker783 - yep! thus my 'not directly' comment. thanks for adding the `ImportExcel` module info! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Doug Finke's awesome module to get this done: https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel

To install it:
`Install-Module ImportExcel`

Then you can do something like this. Note that `Out-File` has a few different encoding options for UTF8: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-5.1#parameters

```bsh
param(
    $excelFilesDir = (Get-ChildItem $PSScriptRoot\excel_files),
    $csvFilesDir = "$PSScriptRoot\csv_files"
)

# NOTE: I had to supply the path to the module on my system. You may not have to.
Import-Module "<ABSOLUTE>:\<PATH>\<TO>\<MODULE>\ImportExcel" -Force
# Import-Module ImportExcel 

if ( (Test-Path -Path $csvFilesDir) -eq $false) { 
    New-Item -Path $csvFilesDir -ItemType Directory -Force 
}
foreach ($file in $excelFilesDir) {
    Import-Excel $file.FullName | `
        ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | `
            Out-File -FilePath "$csvFilesDir\$($file.Name)" -Encoding utf8 -Force
}
```

Comment: this does not work.

is it possible to add to the next code `Content .\template1.csv | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 test-utf8.csv` function so that it reads every file in the folder and executes it?

Comment: @SvyatoslavGuryanov what do you mean by 'it doesn't work'? Are you getting a specific error? It works on my machine. Also, when you say 'reads every file [...] and executes it', do you mean you want to open the CSVs?